# Change pages with UIPageViewController using buttons in my View Controllers swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that let's me navigate between multiple view controller. 
My app works swiping my screen, but I want to remove the swipe gesture to navigate between the pages for different buttons inside my views
This is the code that I'm using on with my page view cxontroller

```
class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

lazy var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let VC1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orangeVC")
    let VC2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blueVC")
    let VC3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "purpleVC")

    return [VC1, VC2, VC3]
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self

    if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first {
        self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)            
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
    let previousIndex = vcIndex-1
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return nil}
    guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else {return nil}

    return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
    let nextIndex = vcIndex+1
    guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else {return nil}
    guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else {return nil}

    return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You only need this line inside the button action

```
self.setViewControllers([viewControllerList[indexHere]], direction: .forward, animated:false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: and how can I get the current view index?

Comment: as here `guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: self.viewControllers.first!) else {return nil}` you may also keep a counter var

Comment: Just, here I have issue, I can't but button on my page view controller, so I tried putting a button on one of my other view controllers. How can I use this on another view controller, or can I add the actions of button on my different view on the same page view controller code?